# Restate a question... in short responses?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, phrase-usage

Can someone please help me understand the meaning of this phrase?

> *to restate a question in short responses*

How can a question (if it's something asked) be restated (paraphrased or repeated or rewritten) through one or more "responses"/answers?

This should refer to some kind of exercise done in reading classes, but honestly I can't figure out an example of it.

Comment: That just looks like a badly written and confusing request to me.  Can you link to the source?

Comment: I found it in a book about teaching tecniques. The author says that «"Show Calling” [a name of one of those techiques] a student whose work contains a common error is also useful because it allows you to address key teaching points efficiently and productively. I observed Maggie Johnson do this in a lesson at Troy Prep. She noticed that multiple students were attempting to restate the question in short responses as she had asked them to do, but were doing so in a stilted, ungrammatical manner, so Maggie approached a student who had struggled with this issue [...]"

Comment: I think the "response" refers to the teacher's asking the students to do it, and so it doesn't mean an acual "answer" to a question. Maybe the response is to be meant as an attempt, e.g. a sentence or "a question restated"...

Comment: Uh… no. That author seems to be thinking in some other language, which really doesn't translate.